# Object doesn't support property or method 'qtip'

Tags: jquery, qtip

```js
function callQtip(textContent, cnt, object_iframe) {
    var iFrameEleId = object_iframe
    $(iFrameEleId).qtip({
        content: {
            prerender: false,
            text: "<div style='width:100%; height:100%;' border='0'><iframe id='iframe" + cnt + "' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' class='frameclass' src='" + textContent + "'&disablelink=y' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' allowTransparency='false'></iframe></div>"
        },
        position: {
            my: "left top",
            at: "left top",
            target: $(iFrameEleId),
            viewport: $(window),
            adjust: {
                method: 'shift',
                x: 420,
                y: -10
            }
        },
        show: {
            solo: false,
            delay: 150
        },
        hide: {
            delay: 350,
            fixed: true,
            event: 'click mouseleave'
        },
        style: {
            classes: "ui-tooltip-blue",
            tip: {
                corner: 'center center',
                mimic: 'center center'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

sorry.. actual coding is like this.

Comment: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/errors-on-ie-object-doesn-t-support-this-property-or-method.  This can be a conflict between javascript libraries requiring jQuery.noConflict()

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have a valid reference to the qtip library. Something like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function 
    callQtip(textContent, cnt, object_iframe){ 
        var iFrameEleId = object_iframe td##popupimg" + cnt); 
        var iFrameEleId = object_iframe
        --->
```

It's because of above your coding is wrong.